# Project Folder getting messed up

Tags: android-studio

I made a folder to store my android projects called "androidstudioprojects" and stored one of my project called MyApplication, now the whole folder itself has become the project. The folder has .idea .gradle app .git folders. I realized this when i got this error "Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme "

Comment: Do you mean the `androidstudioprojects` folder has become an entire project of its own? Also, how do you want the community to help you? Unless you have a specific question here, you won't get much help

Comment: yes the androidstudioprojects have become entire project which is same as MyApplication project but the name is gone. I need to know if there will be any bigger problem becouse of this issue? as I am working on my minor project which is very important .

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, delete the extra files and folders which make it a project. You might have opened the folder in Android studio and studio added .idea and other files thinking it's a project.

Copy the folder somewhere else beforehand though, as a backup. After deleting the contents, try opening the actual project and see if it works properly. If not, I'm guessing you created an actual project named "androidStudioProjects" and your project is added as a module in it. In that case, you need to rename the projects folder to something else, create a new folder for projects and then move this folder in it.